# Does an OCI cardholder travelling to India on a one way ticket require to prove they have funds

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, money, proof-of-funds

Of course I know I will need money to fund my trip, and I do have a certain amount. But would it be a requirement to have a certain amount of funds to travel on a one way ticket from the UK to india? I have an oci card (indian lifelong visa) so I will be staying with family as well. So would I have to show my funds as a requirement/proof.

Thanks

Comment: The requirement to show funds is generally imposed so immigration officials can determine whether a visitor is likely to require public assistance.  Visitors are generally forbidden from doing that.  I don't know what the case is for OCI travelers, but if you have a lifelong right to return to India and reside there, there is probably no funds requirement.

Comment: Agree with phoog. I edited the question because it lists specific circumstances which do not apply for the majority of travelers (an OCI cardholder going to India is very different from an ordinary citizen going to India, so the requirements are different).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, [as per TIMATIC](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=IN&SECTION=pv&SUBSECTION=00&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), with the exception of Japanese nationals applying for a visa on arrival, no one needs to prove sufficient funds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46077/discussion-between-fiksdal-and-iram-ahmed). @IramAhmed